# Inductive Probability in Mathematical Theory

Tags: probability-theory

In M.G. Bullmer's *Principles of Statistics* (Dover edition 1979, though seems like nothing significant was changed from the 1967 second edition), he states in the conclusion to the first chapter that:

> "It has been reluctantly concluded by most statisticians that inductive probability cannot in general be measured and, therefore, cannot be used in the mathematical theory of statistics...it does not seem possible to construct a numerical scale of such (inductive) probabilities."

This sentence struck me as odd, since Wikipedia's article on [Inductive Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_probability) seems to have a wealth of information referencing Bayes Theorem, Inference, and applications in A.I/Machine Learning.

Is this due to the fact that the field of Inductive Probability has grown significantly since the 1960s/1980s?  Since I'm learning probability mainly for applying it to machine learning should I pick up another book on statistics, or are the fundamentals still helpful when applied to ml?

Or is Bullmer's statement still correct? I guess I'm not really sure what a "mathematical model" is and whether the information in the wikipedia article qualifies as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki article referred to says:

"Inductive probability attempts to give the probability of future events based on past events. [...] Bayesian inference broadened the application of probability to many situations where a population was not well defined. But Bayes' theorem always depended on prior probabilities, to generate new probabilities. It was unclear where these prior probabilities should come from."

So, even the Wiki article is **reluctant** about the source of information when telling about prior probabilities.

Here is an example to enlighten the problem with unknown priors:

Assume that we have an unfair coin which we intend to flip twice independently. Let the probability of the heads denoted by $p$ -- this is our prior information. What is the probability that we get heads twice?

The answer seems to be easy: $p^2$ ; what else?

Now, what if we do not know $p$? Then we may assume the existence of a random variable $P$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. So, we imagine that first we (will) observe the event $P=p$ (for some $p$) then we will use this $p$ during  our calculations. In order to do any calculation we need another innocent  looking assumption: Let the two coin flips conditionally independent given the event that $P=p$.

Now,

$$P(head_1 \cap head_2\mid P=p)=p^2,$$
$$P(tail_1\cap tail_2\mid P=p)=(1-p)^2$$
$$P(tail_1\cap head_2\mid P=p)=P(head_1\cap tail_2\mid P=p)=p(1-p).$$
(I hope that my notation is not confusing so far.)

The following calculations will be as easy as confusing:

$$P(head_1)=P(head_2)=\int_0^1 P(head_1\mid P=p) dp=\int_0^1 p \ dp=\frac 12,$$ 
$$P(tail_1)=P(tail_2)=\int_0^1 P(tail_1\mid P=p) dp=\int_0^1 1-p \ dp=\frac 12,$$
$$P(head_1\cap tail_2)=\int_0^1P(head_1\cap tail_2 \mid P=p) dp=$$
$$=\int_0^1 p(1-p) dp=\frac 16\not =P(head_1)P(tail_2).$$

That is, our coin flips turned out to be not independent...

Our assumption about the distribution of the random variable $P$ and the assumption of conditional independence of the coin flips lead us to a contradiction with our most natural hypothesis that the coin flips are independent. This is just a simple example to explain why statisticians are getting reluctant when using traditional probabilistic reasoning in certain cases.

Comment: Oh I see, so the author's essentially saying that, because of situations like above, applying things like calculus to inductive probability is unreliable (and still is, to this day).

Comment: Not exactly that... Applying calculus is OK if we have model. The problem was that we assumed some model(distribution) to model our lack of knowledge. Specificalky: it turned out that the uniform distribution is not a model for the lack of knowledge. In statistics we face this problem frequently. That is, appling probability theory and certain assumptions may be dangerous sometimes.

Comment: I don't understand why the coin flips need to be *conditionally* independent. If we assume total independence instead, we don't get any contradiction, and the result is exactly what you would expect given the symmetry of the situation with no prior knowledge of the coin's behaviour. Is there some motivation that I'm missing for introducing the conditional independence?

Comment: @MorganRogers: The example shows that conditional independence, a natural assumption, contradicts to total independence. That's the point here.

Comment: @zoli but you've shown that it isn't natural since it doesn't work! Perhaps you should replace 'natural' with 'naive'? That seems to be the adjective mathematicians use to describe something which seems intuitive but breaks down on closer inspection.

Comment: @MorganRogers: Assume total independence, OK. What would you say about $P(head_1\cap head_2 \mid P=p)$ and $P(head_i\mid P=p)$. These functions (of $p$) has to exist. Give an example that leads to total independence. (assuming, at the same time, that $P$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @zoli I'm saying that more sensible assumptions would be $P(head_i\mid P=p) = p$ and $P(head_1 \cap head_2)=P(head_1)P(head_2)$. The conditioning is then equivalent to choosing the distribution of $P$ to be concentrated at the single value $P=p$, which gives the correct independence result. Explicitly, $P(head_1 \cap head_2 \mid P=p)=P(head_1 \mid P=p)P(head_2 \mid P=p) = p^2$.

Comment: @MorganRogers: Right. But $p$ is unknown. You could do some calculations unless you assumed a distribution for $P$. The example illustrates that the uniform distribution for $P$ contradicts to independence. The example shows that even in such a simple case it seems to be nonsense to make assumptions regarding $P$. Probability theory is proud to present solutions if the prior distribution are known. Statisticians cannot  share this pride. This is a great debate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43470/discussion-between-morgan-rogers-and-zoli).