# Modelling independent unfair coin flips with unknown parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Physical background:**

We have an unfair coin which we intend to flip twice. We know nothing about the characteristics of this "unfaireness".
We will do our best to flip the coin the second time independently from the first trial.

**Attempted features of the mathematical model:**

We will try to model our lack of knowledge about the coin's unfaireness the following way:

- We assume that there exists a random variable $P$ taking its values from $[0,1]$. Let the distribution of $P$ denoted by $F_P$.
- Assume that $\Bbb P(\operatorname{head}_1\mid P=p)=\Bbb P(\operatorname{head}_2\mid P=p)=p$ and $\Bbb P(\operatorname{tail}_1\mid P=p)=\Bbb P(\operatorname{tail}_2 \mid P=p)=1-p$. The lower index $i=1,2$ refers to the first and the second flip, respectively.
- Under the condition that $P=p$ let the two flips be conditionally independent.
- That is, $\Bbb P(\operatorname{head}_1\cap \operatorname{head}_2\mid P=p)=\Bbb P(\operatorname{head}_2\cap \operatorname{head}_1\mid P=p)=p^2$
- and $\Bbb P(\operatorname{tail}_1\cap \operatorname{tail}_2\mid P=p)=\Bbb P(\operatorname{tail}_2\cap \operatorname{tail}_1\mid P=p)=(1-p)^2$
- and $\Bbb P(\operatorname{tail}_1\cap \operatorname{head}_2\mid P=p)=\Bbb P(\operatorname{head}_1 \cap \operatorname{tail}_2 \mid P=p)=p(1-p).$

**Question:**

Within the model given above, does there exist any non trivial $F_P$ so that the two flips BE independent?
(Non trivial means that there is no $p$ for which $\Bbb P(P=p)=1.$)

**Context:**

Pls. see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878651/inductive-probability-in-mathematical-theory).

Comment: Your choice of notation is a little confusing since you appear to be using $P$ for two different things.

Comment: @smcc: Please explain a little further. ($P$ is a random variable modelling the unfaireness of the coin.)

Comment: Independence means $E(p^2)=P(H_1,H_2)=P(H_1)P(H_2)=E(p)^2$ hence var$(p)=0$ hence $p$ is almost surely constant in the sense that there exists some real number $x$ in $[0,1]$ such that $P(p=x)=1$.

Comment: @zoli You have $P()$ being used to denote the probability of some event as well as being used to denote a random variable.

Comment: @smcc: Yes, true. But hopefully this clumzyness will not cause any misunderstanding.

Comment: @Did: So the trivial case is the only one which can coexist with the assumption of independence and conditional independence. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [your own answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1879094) to a related question, it seems to me that, assuming the existence of a density function $w(p)$ for your distribution $F_P$, we must have
$$\left(\int_0^1 p w(p) dp\right)^2 =\int_0^1 p^2 w(p) dp.$$
But this is precisely stating that $Var(P) = 0$. Hence the only solution is to set $w(p) = \delta(p-y)$ for some $y \in[0,1]$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution; this is precisely the 'trivial' distribution you mentioned.

As I commented on your other answer, I think this result indicates that modelling using conditional independence is not the right thing to do. It seems to me far more sensible to replace this with total independence of the two coin flips, but perhaps you had some other purpose in mind.

Comment: Credit to @Did for pointing this out before me, I had missed their comment.

Comment: Share my acceptance with Did.